# VS Code Opens Folder of Modules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I, probably, have a weird question but it really annoys me. I have created Venv and installed some modules. When I click the module file to scroll it, VS code shows the location of module file in the side explorer. I guess this feature can be turned off in preferences; but, unfortunately, I cannot find it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code to your `setting.json`:

```
"explorer.autoReveal": false
```

Then vscode will not open the floder when you open or click a tab or other things.

Comment: Does my solution solve your problem?